# How to define static class attributes in Python from C++?

Tags: python, c++

I wonder how can I define a static class variable from C++ for Python? The equivalent Python code would be like:

```
class foo:
    bar = int
```

I tried to use tp_getset field when defining the type, but it turns out it doesn't work and returns a `getset_descriptor` in Python, and it doesn't work when called on instances (AttributeError). Furthermore, Python doc says directly manipulating `tp_dict` with C API is unsafe. But it doesn't tell what to use instead. (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_dict))

*I deliberately chose `int` in the example since I'm referencing some other class in it, if that matters.*

Comment: Maybe here you can find the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python

Comment: @magicleon, Yes, that's what I want. But I meant from C++, in a library/module using C-API.

Comment: See [issue #12719](https://bugs.python.org/issue12719) on why accessing `tp_dict` is unsafe.

Comment: @myaut: setting class attributes *during module initialisation* is common practice however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tp_getset` defines [*descriptors*](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) for a type; descriptors are bound to instances when accessed via the `__getattribute__` hook, so are not suitable to define class attributes.

You can add attributes to a class by setting them on the [`PyTypeObject.tp_dict` object](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_dict) for the type; do so in the module's initialization function (`PyInit_<modulename>`), for example, after finalising the type with [`PyType_Ready()`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/type.html#c.PyType_Ready) (which makes sure the `tp_dict` object exists):

```c
PyObject *d;
PyObject *bar;

d = PyFoo_Type.tp_dict;

bar = PyLong_FromLong(42);
if (bar == NULL || PyDict_SetItemString(d, "bar", bar) < 0)
    return NULL;
Py_DECREF(bar);
```

This is untested C code; I'm not familiar enough with C++ to confidently provide you with a C++ version instead.

If you want to see a real-life example, see the [`datetime` module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.2/Modules/_datetimemodule.c#L5650-L5775), where the `datetime.min`, `datetime.max`, etc. class attributes are set.

Comment: Can I say that it's safe to modify `tp_dict` directly before I call `PyModule_AddObject`?

Comment: @YiFei: I believe so; there is an interaction with `PyObject_SetAttrString()` that's not supported, but modifying `tp_dict` in module initialisers is used in multiple places in the Python codebase.

Comment: @YiFei: for example, the `sys` module *deletes* entries from `tp_dict` objects for specific types (removing `__new__` methods to prevent new instances).